# Is it possible to use AOP for web app licence validation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, aop

At present I have a **Spring MVC** web application, which uses **ServletFilter** to filter each HTTP request and check whether the user has really purchased the licence by checking and validating the licence file content.

I have mapped the filter in both spring xml file as well as web.xml appropriately. As I have access to `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` in the filter, I am able to redirect the user to error page if the validation fails.

So, now as the title suggests is it possible to do the same thing using Spring AOP? How can Spring AOP be configured to get access to the request and response objects created by the container to redirect the user?

Comment: Are you expecting the license file to change between requests?  License checking is something that an application would typically do once at startup, not again and again for every request.

Comment: @Wyzard No. Actually I am checking the licence file periodically. Not for each request. But I have some variables in context scope and their status depends on licence file status.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. But it is typically more trouble than it's worth unless you can give us a good use case.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I was wondering how it can be done? It's for learning purposes only. With filters the code is working well and is well tested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can Spring AOP be configured to get access to the request and
>   response objects created by the container to redirect the user?

You won't be able to get the same exact behavior as servlet Filters. A `Filter` operates *around* the target `Servlet` by passing *in* the `ServletRequest` and `ServletResponse` objects. In that sense, you can get similar behavior since AOP advice can operate *around* the joinpoint and intercept arguments that get passed around.

However, the AOP advice can't magically have access to the request and response. It either needs to advise a method that receives them or get them from some `ThreadLocal` or other container. For example, Spring has `RequestContextHolder` which you can use to get the `HttpServletRequest`. But it doesn't have anything to give you the `HttpServletResponse` (not technically true, but it's not reliable). You could write something similar that does.

Once the advice has access to the objects, it can simply invoke `HttpServletResponse#sendRedirect(..)` or `forward()` or whatever.

Comment: Thank you. Suppose I have a controller class method that receives request and response, how can I access them to forward or redirect in the advice code?

Comment: @BRS Match the parameters/arguments in your advice pointcut. Link those to your advice's parameters.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to implement this would be using exceptions. That way the check and the handling can be different in different situation, e.g. web application vs. normal application.

Your check could be added to particular joinpoints using aop. In case it finds something amiss, it would throw a InvalidLicenseException (extends RuntimeException). Now there are several ways in which you can redirect a request to an error page when an exception is thrown. You could add this to your web.xml :

<error-page><exception-type>InvalidLicenseException</exception-type><location>/license-error.jsp</location></error-page>

Since you're using spring, you could also use annotations. Read [this](http://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it out with AOP Advises,

> Advice: Advices are actions taken for a particular join point. In
>   terms of programming, they are methods that gets executed when a
>   certain join point with matching pointcut is reached in the
>   application. You can think of Advices as Struts2 interceptors or
>   Servlet Filters.

So you can configure an advice to take care of validation . you can also configure them to execute at a particular point (i.e) where it needs to be executed .

But remember scope of AOP remains only for method invocation and it doesn't provide response as servlet filters does.

[Learn More ..](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/reference/aop.html)

Simple example [here](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/aop/spring-aop-example/) to start with.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. At present I am actually struggling with advising for each request as I have to have access to request and response. I am able to wire request also in the aspect. But not response.

Comment: Yes as @Soitirios suggested the advices can only invoke `sendRedirect()` or `forward()` methods . not the response